# External JS file not working in XHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I have a file named Reservation.xhtml and in it, I have the script tag in which the external js file is called.The Reservation.xhtml contains a form that i have downloaded from a website and also its javascript which i saved into "validate.js"

```
<script src="validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When using Reservation.xhtml, the functions in the validate.js are not being called but when i change the extension of Reservation.xhtml to Reservation.html..The form works fine..So can anybody tell me why the validate.js works in the Reservation.html and not in the Reservation.xhtml.. Please suggest me how to make it work in Reservation.xhtml

Comment: xhtml extension is not the thing you're looking for. If you want the document to be treated like XHTML, you want to use [the correct doctype](http://www.landofcode.com/web-development-how-to/strict-xhtml-document.php).

Comment: i am using this doctype - is it correct ??
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: I'm not sure - please, google on this topic to get the correct answer. That's what I do every time when I need some doctype. But a question, if I may - are the files on server (http://...) or local (file://...)?

Comment: the files are on xampp

Comment: so then you're on http

Comment: yeah...
I got this problem before but it was with embedded script and i had to use CDATA..But in this case i don't know why it's not working

Comment: Well, more questions: Did you try multiple browsers? What is the linked script doing (I suspect it's validating FORM)? Is it short enough to be posted here? In [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23818636/607407), I've proven that solely the extension and/or doctype are not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yeah i used chrome and firefox

Comment: And what do you say on the not-really-answer then? As you can see from the test files, it's not problem of XHTML.

Comment: Without seeing the complete source of both the XHTML and the Javascript, it's impossible to tell. But yes, there are a great many differences between HTML and XHTML, e.g. you can't put the content of a script element inside <!-- .. -->, because it would literally get commented out. Things like that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [my tests](http://u8.8u.cz/strict.xhtml), there is nothing wrong with the thing you're doing.

I created such file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/ xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Strict document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>This is a strict XHTML document.</p> 
      <div id="validate" style="color:red"><tt>validate.js</tt> has not been called!</div>
      <script src="validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Linked script would alter the innerHTML and style of the div - and it worked in Firefox.

Now while it seems that the file extension and doctype do not matter, there are things that do.
Specifically, [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName) which is a `HTMLElement` property, is different in HTML and XHTML:

> In XHTML (or any other XML format), "span" would be alerted. In HTML, "SPAN" would be alerted instead. - *MDN*

This might cause your script not to perform some operations.

Comment: i used your example but i got the js file called but the fact is when clicking on a button, no function is being triggered..its only when i change the extension of the file from xhtml to html , then it works..

Comment: And do you understand that I'm not *that* powerful soothsayer to know what's wrong with your script unless you share it?